# wide range ultrasound generator

Tags: generator, ultrasound

i want design a wide range ultrasound generator from 20~100 Kilohertz what transducer can do in this range?

the generator must control with volume that change the output frequency this means that we need sweep this range, but usually i see transducer at one frequency,

i do not know information about ultrasound, i want to know is this generator possible or not? i want to design it with micro controller,

i see single frequency pizzoelectrical crystals and some project use 5 or 6 transducer to design it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wide range ultrasound generator\_what transducer can do in this range?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/241295/wide-range-ultrasound-generator-what-transducer-can-do-in-this-range)

Comment: If this was an audio system you'd be looking for a speaker (or speaker system) with a flat or compensatable response in the 20Hz to 20kHz region. Its down to you to find a suitable ultrasonic transducer (system) that has a flat or compensatable response for the the 20 - 100kHz range (n.b. we don't answer shopping questions). If you can't find one the answer to your question is NO. If you can find one the answer is YES.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, this depends on the actual ultrasonic actuator. Since these are extremely likely to be Piezo crystals for the kind of application you're looking at:

> the generator must control with volume that change the output frequency this

That's not how things work.

Frequency is part of the signal that you need to drive your Piezo with. Yes, you can build self-resonant circuits with Piezos, but since you're not going for "easiest way to make a Piezo oscillate at all", but for frequency adjustable oscillation:

You'll need a 20-100 kHz adjustable oscillator. There's plenty of ways to build one – the PWM/timer units of your microcontroller would probably work fine (of course, this depends on a microcontroller. But all ARM microcontrollers that I know of have a PWM/timer unit that can be used to generate adjustable frequency square waves – something totally sufficient to drive your Piezo), and of course, you'll need an amplifier to convert the output of your microcontroller to something that can reliably drive the Piezo at the desired power.

Furthermore: Piezos work both ways, converting a temporally changing voltage to deformation, and also converting a changing deformation to a voltage. In fact, if you get a cigarette lighter with a button: That spark is generated by a Piezo cristal, getting hit by a small hammer.

You don't want such sparks, for example caused by acoustic echos, or dropping the ultrasonic actuator, or something else, to destroy your electronics. Be sure to have transient voltage suppression in place! TVS diodes should work fine.

> do not know information about ultrasound

Obviously, your project is doomed unless you change that. Read Wikipedia about ultrasound generation, Piezos etc. Read existing literature. Don't just hope somehow a good solution will "accidentally" happen – engineering is always a mixture of research and trial & error, and you seem to be a little heavy on the trying, and a little light on the research side.

Comment: thank @user:64158    i want design Electronic insect repellent, and my large problem is in the transducer that can support all this range and i send Single Frequency at each time.

Comment: and i work with arm too, and can generate electrical signal with DAC or PWM , but how can i send it to the environment?